# Módulo Connection no se puede importar

Tags: python, python-2.7, mongodb, ubuntu

Hola estoy aprendiendo un poco MongoDB, ya lo he instalado correctamente en mi PC con Ubuntu, lo estoy tratando de conectar por medio de Python ya he instalado el pymongo con el siguiente comando:

> `sudo pip install pymongo`

Este es mi código en Python:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import Connection
con = Connection()
db = con.BD

alumno = { Nombre : 'Rocio', Matricula : "1502265", Edad : '20', Genero : 'Femenino', Carrera :'N/A'}
alumnos = db.BD
alumnos.insert(alumno)
```

Pero al ejecutar el comando `python prueba.py` para ejecutar el archivo me sale el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mongo.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pymongo import Connection
ImportError: cannot import name Connection
```

¿Alguna idea del porque me sale ese error??

**P.D.:** Ya intenté desinstalando e instalando de nuevo pero aun asi sigue apareciendo el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No existe la clase `Connection`, tal vez lo que estás intentando hacer es:

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient()
```

Como está estipulado en la [documentación](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#making-a-connection-with-mongoclient).